# Jquery .click function not working on chrome but fine on firefox

Tags: jquery

I found same question also posted on stackoverflow but i didn't get right answer so i posted its again what is the reason jquery click function working on firefox but not working on chrome
**Jquery**

```
$("#companypancard").click(function(){

            $(".nav a.active").removeClass("active");
            $("#registrationandlicenses").addClass("active");
            $("#sab2d").hide();

            $("#header-box-content").hide();
            $(".entire-box-content").show();
            $(".line, .back").show();

            $(".h1-content").html("Company Pancard");
            $(".p-discription").html("PAN is mandatory for every organization for financial transition and open a bank account.");
        });
        $("#registrationandlicenses").mouseenter(function(){$("#sab2d").show();});
        $("#sab2d").mouseleave(function(){$("#sab2d").hide();});
```

**EDIT**

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2he4m61f/1/) Is created here

**my code is working on js fiddle but when i upload on server not working on chrome but working on firefox..my 3rd tab is register your business its all sub menu working same code i use on next tab registration and licenses (first submenu) company pan card not working... **

Comment: share your code on jsfiddle

Comment: Share [mcve] with html also so that we can see if there is something wrong in the selectors. Also what does "not working" -mean? An error? Not executing your code? Have you debugged this?

Answer (score 0):

Hope this works for you

```
$(document).on('click', '#companypancard',function(){
     // code to execute
});
```

Comment: Can you please check if javascript is disabled in chrome.

Comment: same code i use on first tab (register your business) working on both browser (chrome,firefox).as it is i use second tab its not working on chrome but fine on firefox..for example please open setyourbiz.com

Comment: I can't see any code on `setyourbiz.com` - the home 'tab' has an href and the about has '#'.  There's no code on either.  If there is, please include it in the question.

Comment: i meant 3rd (setyourbiz.com) tab is register your business and 4th tab is registration and licenses .. 3rd tab working perfect on both browser but same code i use on 4th tab its working on firefox but not working in chrome..

Comment: @RupaliPemare here is my js fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/2he4m61f/1/ 3rd submenu entire working but 4th sub menu (check only first sub menu company pan card) on working on jsfiddle but not working on chrome when i upload it..

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/o2gxgz9r/9480/

https://jsfiddle.net/o2gxgz9r/9481/

```
$(document).on('click', '#companypancard',function(){

});
$("#companypancard").click(function(){

});
```

Both scenario are working in chrome. So check whether your jquery has loaded properly in your page and check your chrome version was supported to your jquery.

Again also you got an error .you just put your code in jsfiddle and send link.